# Mongoose make Array required

Tags: validation, mongoose

I've got a mongoose model that looks something like this:

```
var ProjectSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    tags: [{ type: String, required: true }]
});
```

I want it to be required for a project to have at least one tag. However when I save a new project without a tags array, mongoose does not throw an error:

```
var project = new Project({'name': 'Some name'});
project.save(function(err, result) {
    // No error here...
});
```

What am I missing here? How can I specify an array to be required?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Mongoose 5.x

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#array-required

```
tags: {
    type: [String],
    validate: v => Array.isArray(v) && v.length > 0,
}
```

## Mongoose 4.x

One-liner would be:

```
tags: {type: [String], required: true}
```

[SchemaTypes](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html)

Comment: Nice, just tried it. Didn't know it works that way. Thanks.

Comment: @benjiman be aware that this happily accepts non-String entries in `tags` (which do get caught with the code in my answer), as long as those entries can be cast to `String` by Mongoose.

Comment: if I assign null to tags it works, but if I omit the property the error is not throw

Comment: this is not working for me i try 
qualification : { type: [String], required: true }
and when in input i am not sending key qualification ant it's not throw any error

Comment: @ManojRana http://jasonjl.me/blog/2014/10/23/adding-validation-for-embedded-objects-in-mongoose/  you will get the solution here

Comment: This answer is no longer correct for mongoose 5, as the behavior was changed. See https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5139

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK, you need to set the `type` to `Array` and add a custom validator to make sure that each entry is a `String`:

```
tags : {
  type     : Array,
  required : true,
  validate : {
    validator : function(array) {
      return array.every((v) => typeof v === 'string');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks :-)

Comment: @benjiman can i pass a function required: doSome() and return a true Or false value? if yes, its not working for me. If No, how to add custom validate function to determine the value is required or not?

Comment: @darshanan you should be able to pass a function, but make sure you're passing the _function_ (`doSome`) and not the _result_ of the function (`doSome()`).

Answer (score 1):

OK I tried a new method and it seems to work just fine for mongoose ^5.11.15 I'm not really sure if it's a proper answer in terms of clean code but as far as the functionality which is to make an array of Numbers/Strings required (meaning it won't accept an empty array) it works OK so it's as follows

```
size: [{
        type: Number,
        required: true
}],
```

instead of

```
size: {
        type: [Number],
        required: true
},
```

Instead of defining the type as an array of numbers/strings, I defined the size to be an array of numbers and then the required attribute works as it should it doesn't accept an empty array and raises an error to illustrate that.
again I'm not really sure if this is the best way to define a required array but as far as the functionality it works just fine